Searching in categories AND custom fields
I need to display results that meet two criteria: both the value in the custom field and the category must match. For example, I would like to display all results whose category is ‘Clothing’, and whose custom field meta_easyfatt_libero_1 contains the value ‘MEN’. Here is the code I currently use for custom fields, but I can't figure out how to modify it to fit my requirement.
    <?php
/* Template Name: Template Uomo */
 
get_header(); ?>
 
<div class="easyfatt-products-list">
  <h1><center>Prodotti UOMO</center></h1>
  <?php
  // Imposta il numero di prodotti per pagina e la query
  $paged = (get_query_var('paged')) ? get_query_var('paged') : 1;
  $args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 15, // Mostra 12 prodotti per pagina
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
      array(
        'key' => 'meta_easyfatt_libero_1',
        'value' => 'UOMO',
        'compare' => 'LIKE',
      ),
    ),
  );
 
  $query = new WP_Query($args);
 
  if ($query->have_posts()) { ?>
    <div class="products-grid">
      <?php while ($query->have_posts()) {
        $query->the_post(); ?>
        <div class="product">
 <?php if (has_post_thumbnail()) {
              the_post_thumbnail('medium'); // Mostra l'immagine del prodotto
            } else {
              echo '<img src="' . wc_placeholder_img_src() . '" alt="Placeholder Image">';
            } ?>
          <h2><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
          <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>">Visualizza</a>
        </div>
      <?php } ?>
    </div>
 
    <!-- Paginazione -->
    <div class="pagination">
      <?php
      echo paginate_links(array(
        'total' => $query->max_num_pages,
        'current' => $paged,
      ));
      ?>
    </div>
  <?php
  } else {
    echo '<p>Nessun prodotto trovato in questa categoria.</p>';
  }
 
  wp_reset_postdata();
  ?>
</div>
 
<?php get_footer(); ?>


Adding the tax_query parameter to the $args array with the proper arguments will check for the category as well (untested):
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 15,
    'paged' => $paged,
    'meta_query' => array(
        array(
            'key' => 'meta_easyfatt_libero_1',
            'value' => 'Men',
            'compare' => 'LIKE',
        ),
    ),
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'product_cat',
            'field' => 'name',
            'terms' => 'Clothing',
        ),
    ),
);


Work perfect, thank you!
